# How to convert a string to associate array in php?

Tags: php

I have a string with a line break and spaces in the following format.

```
<?php 
$str = 'Name: XXXXXXXX

Email: XXXX@sample.com

Community: Test Community.';
?>
```

I want to convert this string to array like

```
Array(
   [Name] => XXXXXXXX
   [Email]=> XXXX@sample.com
   [Community] => Test Community.
)
```

My attempt:

```
$str = 'Name: XXXXXXXX Email: XXXX@sample.com Community: Test Community.';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(explode(":", $str)); 
exit;
```

Comment: What is stopping you? Have you tried something?

Comment: Initially, I am tried to explode, but not get an exact result. that's why asking any solution for this case. @B001ᛦ

Comment: Please __provide code__ of your attempt.

Comment: The format looks pretty bad. From where did you get it?

Comment: $str = 'Name: XXXXXXXX

Email: XXXX@sample.com

Community: Test Community.';

echo "<pre>"; print_r(explode(":", $str)); exit; @u_mulder

Comment: __Do not paste code in comments__. [edit] your question.

Comment: This is an email body message i get from imap_fetchbody() function @vivek_23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split the string using the pattern `\n+`. Then make an iteration over the array using array_reduce() got after splitting the string. In every cycle of the iteration explode the string ane prepare. your expected format.

Code example:

```
$str = 'Name: XXXXXXXX

Email: XXXX@sample.com

Community: Test Community.';

$elm = preg_split('/\n+/', $str);
$data = array_reduce($elm, function ($old, $new) {
    $key_value = explode(':', $new);
    $old[$key_value[0]] = $key_value[1];
    return $old;
}, []);

print_r($data);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/G9QqD).

Comment: Glad to help you @BalakumarB :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` with `array_walk` & `explode`

```
$c = array_filter(explode('
', $str));
$r = [];
array_walk($c, function($v, $k) use (&$r){
  $arr = explode(':', $v);
  $r[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
});
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/fgKnE

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your elements in an array then push it in another array as below :

```
$array = array();

$element = array("name"=>"xxxxx", "email"=>"xxx@sample.com", "community"=>"Test Comunity");
array_push($array, $element);

dump($array);die;
```